# How to call a method in a javascript module from another module referencing the context of 'this' from the first module

Tags: javascript, callback, this

I have one module that I'm using for helper methods, in this module I have a method that will set a keyup eventListener on an element that's passed in. I want to call that helper method from a separate module and pass in a callback using the current modules 'this' context.

```
//helper module constructor---
function ToolsHelper(options) {
    "use strict";
    this.init(options);
}
//helper module methods---
;(function ($, ba) {
    "use strict";
    ToolsHelper.prototype = {
        constructor: ToolsHelper,
        spaceEnterEvent: function (ele, callback) {
           var spaceKey = 13,
               enterKey = 32;
            if (callback === 0) {
                callback = null;
            }
            ele.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                var targ = e.target;
                if (e.keyCode === spaceKey || e.keyCode === enterKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    targ.click();
                    if (callback !== null) {
                       callback();
                    }
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    }

    $(document).on("baCoreReady", function () {
        ba.ToolsHelper = new ToolsHelper();
    });

})(jQuery, ba);
```

I'm attempting to call this helper from another module [moduleB] using:

```
ba.ToolsHelper.spaceEnterEvent(trigger, self.updateTabIndexes);
//'self' is set to 'this' in moduleB
```

Once self.updateTabIndexes() is fired from within moduleB im getting 'cannot read property "settings" of undefined' error - *'settings' is an object defined from within moduleB*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the context for `updateTabIndexes` when passing it as a callback:

```
ba.ToolsHelper.spaceEnterEvent(
  trigger, 
  self.updateTabIndexes.bind(self) // bind the context here
);
```

**Why**

In short, the way `this` gets bound within a function depends entirely on how the function is called, not where its defined.

You may have your function `updateTabIndexes` defined somewhere in moduleB as a method on an object, but you are passing it into the `ToolsHelper` as a plain function. Whenever a function is called on its own (i.e. `f()`), its context is bound to the global object or `undefined` if in strict mode.

Comment: like a charm!! - never thought about being able to bind from the call - thanks for the help and clarification!

Comment: you're welcome mate, glad to help